# Upload images with random name and also delete older image from the directory

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload an image with a random name, also when I update the image, I want the previous image to be deleted.

Code below:

```
  $banner=$_FILES ['banner']['name'];
  $upload="../image/banner/";
  $target_file = $upload.basename($_FILES["banner"]["name"]);
  $imagefiletype= pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["banner"]["tmp_name"], $target_file );
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is "_the previous image_"? You should also show some effort and paste your code, there's nothing regarding randomness or deleting the old file in what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

When update your new images at that time first store old image name in variable. after update true then delete old image in your directory using "unlink" function.

```
$old_image = "xyz" // store old image name
```

after update query success

```
unlink('../image/banner/'.$old_image); // delete old image in your directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
$path = 'image/folder/'; $unique_name=time().uniqid(rand()); 
$File_with_location = $path . $unique_name . '.' . strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['img']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); 
$filename = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];        
move_uploaded_file($filename,  $File_with_location);
```

for deleting old image you can use this

```
$path = './root/home/folder/file.jpg';
if (unlink($path)) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```